# Script ssh para hacer backup de la base de datos: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure

Tags: mysql, ssh

Tengo el siguiente script<sup>1</sup> el cual utilizo para hacer copias de seguridad de la base de datos de forma automática:

```
# List of databases to be backed up separated by space
dblist="nombre_bd"
user="usuario"
pass="password"


# Directory for backups 
# Dando un nombre no convencional al directorio para despistar a los intrusos :)
backupdir=/home/.nonconventional/db

# Number of versions to keep
numversions=4

# Full path for MySQL hotcopy command
# Please put credentials into /root/.my.cnf
#hotcopycmd=/usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy
hotcopycmd="/usr/bin/mysqldump -u$user -p$pass --lock-tables --databases"

# Create directory if needed
mkdir -p "$backupdir"
if [ ! -d "$backupdir" ]; then
   echo "Invalid directory: $backupdir"
   exit 1
fi

# Hotcopy begins here
echo "Dumping MySQL Databases..."
RC=0
for database in $dblist; do
   echo
   echo "Dumping $database ..."
   mv "$backupdir/$database.gz" "$backupdir/$database.0.gz" 2> /dev/null
   $hotcopycmd $database | gzip > "$backupdir/$database.gz"

   RC=$?
   if [ $RC -gt 0 ]; then
     continue;
   fi

   # Rollover the backup directories
   rm -fr "$backupdir/$database.$numversions.gz" 2> /dev/null
   i=$numversions
   while [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
     mv "$backupdir/$database.`expr $i - 1`.gz" "$backupdir/$database.$i.gz" 2> /dev/null
     i=`expr $i - 1`
   done
done

if [ $RC -gt 0 ]; then
   echo "MySQL Dump failed!"
   exit $RC
else
   # Hotcopy is complete. List the backup versions!
   ls -l "$backupdir"
   echo "MySQL Dump is complete!"
fi
exit 0
```

El script está programado como un cron y funciona bien, me hace las copias de seguridad.

Está programado para enviarme un email cada vez que se hace la copia, lo cual ocurre, pero el email me manda siempre esta advertencia:

```
Dumping MySQL Databases...

Dumping base_de_datos ...
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
total 235280


  .... lista de archivos de copias de seguridad


MySQL Dump is complete!
```

El error es porque en esta línea del script:

```
hotcopycmd="/usr/bin/mysqldump -u$user -p$pass --lock-tables --databases"
```

Estoy pasando directamente el nombre de usuario y la contraseña en la línea de comandos.

Si se analiza el script, hay dos líneas comentadas:

```
# Please put credentials into /root/.my.cnf
#hotcopycmd=/usr/bin/mysqlhotcopy
```

El script original recomendaba que ponga las credenciales en el archivo `.my.cnf`, evitando así pasarlas en la línea de comandos.

El problema es que no tengo acceso a ese archivo, por encontrarme en un hosting compartido.

La pregunta es si hay alguna manera de evitar esa advertencia de seguridad que estoy recibiendo constantemente. Si es posible me gustaría saber también cuál es el riesgo real que estoy corriendo al dejar el script como está actualmente. El mismo lleva un tiempo funcionando y no ha habido problemas, pero el mensaje en los emails no deja de ser preocupante.

---

1. Código original en [*Automated MySQL Database Backup*](https://rimuhosting.com/howto/mysqlbackup.jsp) (version 2)

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar `--defaults-file` con un archivo en el que configurar un usuario y contraseña?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Te recomiendo crear tu propio archivo de configuración (por ejemplo `/home/miusuario/.credenciales.cnf`) con permisos de lectura únicamente para el usuario que desees que contenga:

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = usuario
password = password
socket   = <el que sea u omitirlo>
```

Luego basta con cambiar en tu script:

```
hotcopycmd="/usr/bin/mysqldump --defaults-file=/home/miusuario/.credenciales.cnf --lock-tables --databases"
```

Comment: Te me has adelantado :) +1

Comment: Gracias. Ahora pruebo. ¿Lo que comentabas sobre `--defaults-file` debo aplicarlo también?  ¿En qué parte del código?

Comment: Ya he cambiado yo la respuesta para que aparezca el código exacto que debes cambiar (yo tuve que cancelar mi respuesta cuando se me adelantó x).

Comment: Gracias. He quitado el usuario y contraseña que ya no se necesita

Comment: Ups, ¡fallo mío! x`] PD: Veo que en la pregunta @A.Cedano hay un anexo preguntando sobre las implicaciones de dejar el script tal cual. ¿Me permites editar tu pregunta para responder?

Comment: Para que te vayas haciendo una idea, es por motivos de no dejar en el historial de la shell los datos de usuario y contraseña y que estos puedan ser accedidos por terceras personas por mala configuración de los permisos y minimizar el riesgo de fuga de esa información por otros motivos o vectores de entrada. (sigue)

Comment: Al fin y al cabo, si alguien consigue acceder a tu cuenta podrá acceder al archivo de configuración de igual manera que lo haría a tu histórico de comandos, por lo que suele apoyarse en una configuración de (por ejemplo) `sudo` para que permita hacer uso de ese archivo desde otro usuario sin teclear la contraseña únicamente junto al comando `mysqldump`, sin posibilidad de acceder a su contenido desde el usuario de trabajo. También, imagino, que se hace para evitar que si se lanza desde un planificador de tareas, éste mande información de depuración con las credenciales en texto plano.

Comment: Funciona a las mil maravillas, gracias a ti y también a @OscarGarcia. Creo que sería bueno indicar los riesgos que indicaba la advertencia. El script funcionó así durante algún tiempo y no sabía exactamente a lo que me exponía dejándolo como estaba. Gracias a tus respuesta la advertencia ha desaparecido.

Comment: Es correcto lo que dices @OscarGarcia. Revisando en el histórico de comandos bash aparece precisamente el comando de backup incluyendo la contraseña. Ahora bien, ese archivo está de mi lado (hosting compartido). ¿Puede algún otro usuario tener acceso a él? Explorando (vía SFTP o SSH) yo no veo nada de los otros usuarios, aunque si reviso el error_log  desde cPanel puedo ver por ejemplo errores que ocurren en los dominios de los otros usuarios con respecto a PHP, intentos de ataques, etc. Me salen incluso los nombres de dominios y otras cosas que se escriben en el log de errores.

Comment: Si el alojamiento compartido está bien configurado no deberías temer nada. Tendrías el mismo riesgo de que accedieran a tus archivos PHP de configuración de credenciales de MySQL. Son consejos de buenas costumbres para minimizar el riesgo de exposición de datos de credenciales. Por norma general se recomienda que se ponga únicamente `-p` cuando se ejecuta manualmente y teclear la contraseña a mano.