# dump de mysql desde php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Tengo un problema con el código que estoy usando, tengo que hacer un respaldo de una base de datos con dump desde php el código crea el respaldo pero este está vacío.

```
<?php
    
    $db_host = 'localhost'; //Host del Servidor MySQL
    $db_name = 'si'; //Nombre de la Base de datos
    $db_user = 'root'; //Usuario de MySQL
    $db_pass = ''; //Password de Usuario MySQL
    
    $fecha = date("Ymd-His"); //Obtenemos la fecha y hora para identificar el respaldo
 
    // Construimos el nombre de archivo SQL Ejemplo: mibase_20170101-081120.sql
    $salida_sql = $db_name.'_'.$fecha.'.sql'; 
    
    //Comando para genera respaldo de MySQL, enviamos las variales de conexion y el destino
    $dump = "mysqldump --h$db_host -u$db_user -p$db_pass --opt$db_name cliente --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > $salida_sql";
    //mysqldump -u $db_user  -p $db_name --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > si-backup-$(date +%F)
    system($dump, $output); //Ejecutamos el comando para respaldo
    
    $zip = new ZipArchive(); //Objeto de Libreria ZipArchive
    
    //Construimos el nombre del archivo ZIP Ejemplo: mibase_20160101-081120.zip
    $salida_zip = $db_name.'_'.$fecha.'.zip';
    
    if($zip->open($salida_zip,ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)===true) { //Creamos y abrimos el archivo ZIP
        $zip->addFile($salida_sql); //Agregamos el archivo SQL a ZIP
        $zip->close(); //Cerramos el ZIP
        unlink($salida_sql); //Eliminamos el archivo temporal SQL
        header ("Location: $salida_zip"); // Redireccionamos para descargar el Arcivo ZIP
        } else {
        echo 'Error'; //Enviamos el mensaje de error
    }
?>
```

Si alguien sabe porque falla me sería de mucha ayuda ya revisé y no doy con el problema.
Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Qué tan grande es la BD? Cual es el tiempo estimado para la operación? Ya verificaste que la operación no desborde los límites de tiempo? verifica con var_dump() los tiempos en distintos puntos del proceso, (de ser necesario pon exit(); luego de var_dump() para devolver algo si no ves que llega al final. Si llega al final verifica los permisos para crear archivos y, si puedes verifica que el .zip se haya creado.

Comment: Imprime `$dump` y ejecútalo desde línea de comandos para verificar si en ese caso se crea el dump correctamente. Entonces podría ser otro tipo de error, como lo que te comenta @quevedo. De todos modos puede que no sea una buena idea lanzar esto desde PHP. Este tipo de operaciones, que suelen demandar muchos recursos (sobre todo en BD grandes) es mejor programarlas a otro nivel (script de ssh para Linux, cmd script para Windows, etc). Luego puedes programar un Cron que lance tu archivo para hacer el backup cada X tiempo. Mira [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/231604/29967).

Comment: hola:
Es solo una tabla con 20 registros es algo más conceptual, el archivo se crea, pero creo que el dump no sé ejecuta puede que sea problema de permisos.

Comment: --h$db_host ¿Estas seguro que no te da problema tener la variable pegada del sql? Es decir colocar un espacio así --h $db_host lo mismo aplica para el resto de los parametros.

Answer (score 0):

Para el comando mysqldump no puedes juntar los parámetros que envías como lo haces con `-p` o con `-u` (cosa que haces con -h y --opt), por lo que **lo siguiente**:

```
$dump = "mysqldump --h$db_host -u$db_user -p$db_pass --opt$db_name cliente --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > $salida_sql";
```

**Pasaría a**:

```
$dump = "mysqldump -h $db_host -u$db_user -p$db_pass --opt $db_name cliente --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > $salida_sql";
```

De igual forma, para indicar el hostname en lugar de `--h` utiliza `-h`  o `--host`

```
$ -> man -P cat mysqldump | grep 'host_name'
       ·   --host=host_name, -h host_name
```

Del resto el script genera el .zip y si descomprimes tendrás el .sql correcto. He usado el script y he importado la base de datos manualmente y funciona correcto.

Comment: Nota: si eso, controla el dump con una excepción para que en caso de no generar el .sql no te comprima nada. Si intentas meter una contraseña errónea por ejemplo, el programa continúa y te generará un .zip igual aunque no te valga de nada.

Comment: hola:
Estuve probando el comando en la terminal  y como a muchos en internet me sale acceso denegado, pero si le paso la clave por separado pasa, no sé si será algo mio o no.
Probé el código de Adrian pero sigue lo mismo crea el archivo vacio, gracias por responder a todos,
pd: lo que si estoy en windows con xampp me imagino que eso está afectando

Comment: Si cambias la línea que te comenté debería funcionarte. Copié el mismo script cambiando los parámetros de la BD y corrigiendo lo que te comenté y me hace el .sql y lo empaqueta correctamente. Intenta ejecutar el comando a mano del mysqldump, si este te falla entonces te creará el .zip vacío y ya no sería cosa del script: `mysqldump -h localhost -u usuario -pPassword --opt nombreBD Tabla --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false > dump.sql";` (mejor si no colocas la contraseña por CLI).

Comment: ¿Pudiste solucionarlo finalmente?