# back up de base de datos SQL con PHP

Tags: php, sql

Necesito realizar un back up de una base de datos, en especifico de una tabla, que es la que guarda todos mis registros. Encontré este código.

```
<?php
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'prueba';
$db_table = 'asesoria';
$db_user = 'root';
$db_pass = '';

$fecha = date("Ymd-His");

$salida_sql = $db_name.'_'.$fecha.'.sql';

$dump = "mysqldump --h$db_host -u$db_user -p$db_pass --opt $db_name > $salida_sql";
system($dump, $output);

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$salida_zip = $db_name.'_'.$fecha.'.zip';

if($zip->open($salida_zip, ZipArchive::CREATE) === True){
    $zip->addFile($salida_sql);
    $zip->close();
    unlink($salida_sql);
    header("location: $salida_zip");
}else{
    echo'error';
}
?>
```

Y en efecto me crea un archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al importar el archivo no contiene nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para que entren un poco en contexto, el sistema debe cargar en la tabla asesorías, múltiples registros, y el back up es con la finalidad de que cada cierto periodo el administrador pueda borrar únicamente los registros y empezar de cero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia?, alguna forma de solo realizar el back up de la tabla?

Comment: No se que opciones tienes en tu phpmyadmin, pero en el mio, para subir un archivo ZIP me pide que tenga esta extensión: `.[formato].[compresión]`. Por ejemplo: `.sql.zip`.   Si tu archivo ZIP tiene un tamaño considerable (no es 0 bytes) prueba renombrandolo a esa extensión.  Ten en cuenta que mysqldump es probable que tenga una instruccion CREATE, y si la tabla ya existe es probable que no la sobreescriba. Por lo tanto borra la tabla antes de la importación tambien. Y por último, comprueba el archivo SQL contenido en el ZIP y abrelo con un editor (si es pequeño) para ver si tiene registros

Comment: Yo haría los backups desde la consola. [Aquí hay un script de ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/231604/29967). Luego, puedes programar un cron para que ejecute ese script cada cierto tiempo, creando los backups en la carpeta que tú le indiques sin necesidad de intervención alguna. Otra ventaja es que si la BD es muy grande, el código trabajará más rápido que si lo haces desde PHP.